# What is the function for returning part of a character, binary, text, or image expression in c# in Windows mobile?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-mobile

What is the function for returning part of a character, binary, text, or image expression in C# in Windows mobile? Because `Substring()` function does not work in Windows Mobile.

Comment: r u making application for windows phone 7 or windows mobile 6.5 or so ?

Comment: @Bhavik, why have you added `windows-phone-7` tag? It looks like it is more related to previous windows mobile platform.

Comment: "a character, binary, text, or image expression in C#" could you define that 'expression' term?

Comment: It's not possible to return "part of a character" (you can return 1 or more, but nothing fractional) using Substring().  Images, as well as most binary, think of these as byte arrays ... return as little or as much as you like.

Answer (score 1):

[Substring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hxthx5h6%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is apparently supported by most mobile frameworks.  From MSDN:

*Supported By*

Windows 98, Windows Server 2000 SP4, Windows CE, Windows Millennium Edition, **Windows Mobile for Pocket PC, Windows Mobile for Smartphone**, Windows Server 2003, Windows XP Media Center Edition, Windows XP Professional x64 Edition, Windows XP SP2, Windows XP Starter Edition

The Microsoft .NET Framework 3.0 is supported on Windows Vista, Microsoft Windows XP SP2, and Windows Server 2003 SP1.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a character from a string you can try:

```
string str="abc";
char firstChar=str[0];
```